# Connection refused in Gravitee.io

Tags: gravitee

I just started [Gravitee](https://gravitee.io/downloads/apim/index.html) gateway and Management API. But I keep getting this error.

```
Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:9200
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elasticsearch instance must be available for the API gateway.